# Javascript regex parsing

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking to parse some formatting out of a field using javascript. My rule is catching some extra things which I need to fix. The regex is:

```
/[\((\)\s)-]/g
```

This regex is properly cleaning up: `(123) 456-7890` the problem I'm having is that it is also removing all spaces rather than just spaces following a closing parentheses. I'm no expert in regex but it was my understanding that `(\)\s)` would only remove the closing parentheses and space combo. What would the correct regex look like? It needs to remove all parentheses and dashes. Also, only remove spaces immediately following a closing parentheses.

The outcomes I would like are such.

The replace method i am using should work as such

```
var str = mystring.replace(/[\((\)\s)-]/g, '');
```

`(123) 456-7890` should become `1234567890` which is working.

`leave me alone` should stay `leave me alone` the issue is that it is becoming `leavemealone`

Comment: Can you show exactly what output you expect from a given input, instead of just describing it? That will make it much easier to provide the desired solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
var str = mystring.replace(/\)\s*|\(\s*|-/g, '');
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
\)\s* : Open parenthesis followed by any number of whitespace
|     : OR
\(\s* : Close parenthesis followed by any number of whitespace
|     : OR
-     : Hyphen
```

Since parenthesis are regex-metacharacters used for grouping they need to be escaped when you want to match them literally.

Comment: Thanks codaddict. Using the `or` makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Placing everything in brackets (`[]`) creates a class of characters to match anywhere in the input. Taking your requirements literally ("remove all parentheses, dashes and spaces immediately following a closing parentheses"):

```
"(123) 456-789 0".replace(/\)[\(\)\s-]+/g, ")")
```

Output:

```
"(123)456-789 0"
```

This matches (essentially) the same character class, but specifies that these characters immediately follow a closing parenthesis.

Comment: I've clarified the requirement, it should only remove spaces directly after a closing parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ensure that there is a paranthesis or something else preceding the space:

```
(?<=\))\s
```

------------ OLD ANSWER ----------

If you want to remove all paranthesis, dashes and spaces, you would go with something like this:

```
/[\s-\(\)]+/g
```

[something] - would look for anything that is in the brackets (letters s, o, m, e, t, h, i, n, g).

\s = white space

( = paranthesis

) = paranthesis

+ = at least one or more occurance of what is preceding it (which would be paranthesis, white space and dashes)

Comment: thank you for your answer, I do not want to remove all spaces, that is what it is currently doing. I asked that it only remove spaces following a closing parentheses.